# How to let DELETE to remove the rows with no constraint problem anyways?

Tags: sql, postgresql

When there is a constraint and one tries to DELETE data on a relation, but some rows can't be deleted because some constraint, how can one Select those rows that had no problem with the constraint to delete them anyways?

Example:

- Table `h1` has 2 elements: `h1_1` and `h1_2`
- Table `h2` has 1 element: `h2_1`
- `h2_1` refers by *Foreign Key constraint* to `h1_1`.

So, a simple `DELETE FROM h1` will fail by that restriction.

How to DELETE `h1_2`?

Instead of simply `DELETE from h1 WHERE f(value) == 'h1_2'`...

... I was hoping for a kind of error management solution that simply ignore what it can't remove, but proceed when no problem arise.

WHY? The reason is explained below:

**THE VALUE OF THIS**

The value of this is in cases where there is a really deep hierarchy by Foreign Keys with DELETE ON CASCADE.

If this was something, I could delete the top element and all it's descendant but still protect data in a really low position in the hierarchy by removing the CASCADE on DELETE in it's FOREIGN KEY Constraint.

Example:

```
h1
\- CASCADE- h2.1
|           \-CASCADE-h3.1
|           |         \-CASCADE- h4.1
|           |         \-NO-CASCADE- h4.2 <=== PROTECTED BY NO-CASCADE
|           \-CASCADE-h3.2
\- CASCADE- h2.2
```

Then One could remove all the h1 records and it's descendants which has no element in h4.2 referencing transitively to them some how, by simple calling the DELETE sentence with the "IGNORE" mechanism:

```
DELETE WHAT-YOU-CAN FROM h1;
```

There would be no code specific to this Hierarchy, no knowledge of what refers to what.

Is there something like that in Postgres... or SQL anyways? Something similar to `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if you can solve it with basic SQL but in PL/pgSQL it is possible to catch the exceptions.

```
do $$
declare
    x mytable%rowtype;
begin
    for x in select * from mytable
    loop
      begin
        delete from mytable where id = x.id;
      exception when others then
        null;
      end;
    end loop;
end;
$$;
```

Comment: This actually solves the problem. I'll wait a bit more to see if somebody comes with a solution similar to the `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` of the UPDATE/INSERT

Comment: There is nothing similar to "on conflict" in [delete](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-delete.html). Nor will it be there in v13.

Comment: Thank you very much @Belayer.
So, I marked this answer as the correct one.
Now I'm intrigued: how do you know what you said?

Comment: I read the documentation. Follow the link provided to the section on the delete statement. The Synopsis shows every valid phase in the statement, the Description following that describes them all. There is no *on conflict* therefore it is not valid nor does anything in the description contain anything similar to the on conflict. Therefore there is nothing like it. Learn your way around the documentation it contains everything you need - admittedly not always the clearest, but it is there.

Comment: @Belayer I was more intrigued by how do you know the future of Postgres (v13 you mentioned) than the actual answer you gave :D Thank you.

Comment: The documentation for v13 is available on there site. I checked there. It is of course just still in beta, but round 3. I think it is safe to say it will not be in the final release either.